# convert large txt.gz file to sqlcontext dataframe object in pyspark for text analytics

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nlp

I am still trying to learn pyspark, it almost seems like a foreign language to me. So I downloaded a large text file with Amazon reviews it it.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('app')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
```

This is what the raw file looks like:

```
sc.textFile('/home/john/Downloads/Software.txt.gz').take(12)

['product/productId: B000068VBQ',
 'product/title: Fisher-Price Rescue Heroes: Lava Landslide',
 'product/price: 8.88',
 'review/userId: unknown',
 'review/profileName: unknown',
 'review/helpfulness: 11/11',
 'review/score: 2.0',
 'review/time: 1042070400',
 'review/summary: Requires too much coordination',
 "review/text: I bought this software for my 5 year old. He has a couple of the other RH software games and he likes them a lot. This game, however, was too challenging for him. The biggest problem I see is that the game requires the child to be able to maneuver the vehicle using all 4 scroll keys on the keyboard. During one exercise, which by the way you can't get to the next level until you complete this exercise, the game requires that you use the keys to move while watching out for falling lava rocks and clouds, monitor a fuel gauge, watch arrow indicators that help you determine where objects are in the arena below, and watch a scope that shows animals when you're hovering over the top of them.I tried to perform this exercise myself and got frustrated. It's just too hard to expect even a 7 year old to complete this exercise let alone a 5 year old.There are some exercises he can complete himself but they mostly require using the left, right keys.I don't know who this game would be good for. Parts of it would be too easy for someone 7 or older. Yet some parts are too difficult for those younger than that.",
 '',
 'product/productId: B000068VBQ']
```

Notice we have "product/productID", "product/title", ... etc. There are 10 different categories and then an empty list, then the categories start all over with "product/productID", "product/title", ...etc.

I created a parser to separate items right of the colon:

```
def parse(x):
    result = x.split(':')
    if len(result)==1:
        return "SEPARATOR"
    else:
        return result[1]
Data1 =sc.textFile('/home/john/Downloads/Software.txt.gz').map(parse)
```

I use the same function but `return result[0]` to get the values to the left of the colon, assign it to `Data0`

I figured zipping them together then doing a groupByKey would get all the entries for "product/productID", "product/title", ... "review/text" grouped together into key-value pairs. And in a sense it worked:

```
zipped = Data0.zip(Data1)
f = sorted(zipped.groupByKey().mapValues(list).collect())
```

Now, f is a list of tuples, and it looks like this:

```
('product/price',
 [' 8.88',
  ' 8.88',
  ' 8.88',
  ' 8.88',
  ' 8.88',
  ' 8.88',
  ' 8.88',
  ' unknown',
  ' unknown',
  ' unknown',
  ' unknown',
   .
   .
   .
```

What I am really trying to do is get it into a SQLContext dataframe with the keys as column names and all the entries to the right as item entries for the column. I am having trouble finding examples on this, or documentation from Spark on how to do this. I can convert it back to an RDD object easily enough,

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(f)
```

And this gives me key-value pairs but now how do I turn that into a spark dataframe?